# nginx on Debian: set startup conf file?

Tags: nginx, debian

I have installed nginx on Debian:

```
apt-get install nginx-full
```

I see that it automatically starts itself up (and does so as root) which is annoying, but tolerable.

My problem is then setting the startup conf file.   How can I modify the startup nginx daemon to always use my conf?  (and also hopefully root prefix)

Ideally I'd like to modify the daemon to do something like:

```
nginx -c $MY_PATH/site/nginx/conf/nginx-www-phantomjscloud.conf -p $MY_PATH -s reload
```

Comment: why not edit `nginx.conf` ? , you can change any thing there, even the annoying `user` that nginx runs as

Comment: it's because i have an automated deployment process, and dislike messing with the application installed files.  right now i set my cron job to shut down nginx and running my own nginx with my config.  but that's a bit hacky

Comment: you could take a backup to `nginx.conf.bak` for example and edit the original, those files are made to be edited , or the second option is creating a copy of `/etc/init.d/nginx` and create your own service with your own parameters, then you could simply run `service mynginx start` for example

Comment: how do i stop nginx from auto starting then?

Comment: I believe if you stop the service once it shouldn't start again by it self